# Getting non-singular (invertible) matrix from a singular one

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am struggling with specific matrices that are singular, but I would like to make them invertible (non-singular). My first ideas are:

1. to eliminate certain rows and columns;
2. to find "healthy" submatrices.

I am a practitioner, not a mathematician, so I apologize if this question is trivial.

Anyway: how can I get a well-behaving matrix? Maybe some R or Python code, on top?

Many, many thanks,

PM

Comment: This is not a trivial problem. There are many ways to achieve this, but they serve different purposes. For example, if you want your resulting matrix to be close to the original in the $2$-norm sense, you can find the singular value decomposition of the matrix first, then remove singular vectors corresponding to zero singular values.

Comment: What does "well-behaving" mean? What do you want this process to achieve? If you just want to get an invertible matrix out of it, that's trivial: just discard your original and take the identity matrix.

Comment: The references in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoinverse) might be useful.

Comment: Note the two methods you suggest (which seem to me to be the same) won't work for the zero matrix, and for a rank one matrix (where every row is a multiple of the same non-zero vector) you have to eliminate all rows and columns but one.

Comment: I suggest reading "[Making a singular matrix non-singular](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2012/06/13/matrix-condition-number/)" by John D. Cook.

Comment: What do you mean by obtaining a non singular matrix? You can check out Kaltofan and Saunders 1991 On Wiedmann's Method of Solving Linear Equations. Assuming your field has large enough, one can choose a random upper triangular matrix $U$ and random lower triangular matrix $L$ (with certain condition) such that the top left submatrix of $UAL$ is invertible for all submatrix of size rank($A$).

Comment: Every singular matrix is _close_ to a non-singular matrix. So add a small perturbation, which is large enough to create a matrix with an acceptable condition number, e.g. `A = A + rand(n,n)/1e8`